# selectInput: Have Multiple = TRUE and filter based off that

Tags: r, widget, shiny

I have a shiny app as follows:

My goal here is to be able to filter multiple values from the Type column based off of the selectInput ui feature. When I do the

`selectInput(inputId, label, choices, multiple = TRUE)`, the filtering doesn't work because it is expecting 1 response.

Below is the working version, but I can't figure out how to utilize the multiple feature in SelectInput.

I am currently using

```
test1<-filter(test, `Type`==input$file4)
```

and this doesn't work when I add this extension to `multiple=TRUE`

server

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

actor <- c('Matt Damon','George Clooney','Brad Pitt', 'Clive Owen', 'Morgan Freeman', 'Edward Norton', 'Adrian Granier')
category<-c('action', 'action', 'noir', 'action', 'thriller', 'noir', 'action')
movie <- c('Oceans Eleven', 'Oceans Twelve', 'Fight Club', 'Children of Men', 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'American History X', 'Entourage')
movies <- c(21, 23, 26, 12, 90, 14, 1)
cost <- c(210000, 2300000, 260000, 120000, 90000, 140000, 10000)
Type <- c('A','B','C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A')

moviedata<-data.frame(actor, category, movie, movies, cost, Type)

shinyServer(function(input,output){
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read_csv(file=file1$datapath)

  })


    output$sum <- renderDataTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    test<-subset(moviedata, category %in% data()[[1]])
    test1<-filter(test, `Type`==input$file4)
    test1$`BUDGET`<-input$file5
    test1$CHECKING<-ifelse(test1$`BUDGET`>test1$cost,"YES", "NO")
    filter(test1, CHECKING=="YES")
  })

  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Powered by", tags$img(src='optimatic.png'))
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Summary", dataTableOutput("sum")))
   })

} 
)
```

ui

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Actor Finder"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file","Upload Category List: Must have category as header"),
      selectInput("file4", "Select Type", c("A" = "A",
                                            "B" = "B",
                                            "C" = "C"), selected = "A",
                                            multiple=FALSE),
      numericInput("file5", "Choose cost", 1000000000),
      tags$hr()),    
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")
    )

  )
))
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: use `%in%` instead of `==`

Comment: thank you, didn't realize it was that simple

Comment: @HubertL how would I add another selection to include missing values with NA?

Comment: Add "Missing" choice to file4 then `test1<-filter(test, Type %in% input$file4 | (is.na(Type) & "Missing" %in% input$file4 ) )`

Comment: thanks, if you want to put these down as answers I can give you credit for this?

Comment: Two years later! This is still a simple yet perfect answer, thanks @H

Comment: @HubertL Thanks. Please write an answer so you get credit and people can see faster that this question was answered

Comment: Done @PeterDieter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When filtering on multiple selection you can not use `==` because there is a list of selected values. You can use `%in%` instead:

```
test1<-filter(test, Type %in% input$file4)
```

To include missing values with NA you can add a "Missing" choice to file4 then:

```
test1<-filter(test, Type %in% input$file4 | 
                    (is.na(Type) & "Missing" %in% input$file4 ))
```